# How do I make the texture paint value match the colour ramp values

Tags: shaders, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, toon-shading

I've painted a texture in grey scale with the values of the colours being used to match the level of shading allowed and colouring of the model in the shaders. It's my attempt at creating my own [GGST shader](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ejZ9TrIFNwiawLcFj-XRtaO3Vg9TxD04sR8HKOaRkGI/edit?usp=sharing). When the texture image is plugged into a fac colour ramp I notice the values are way off, I'd like to know why and if possible how I can match them up?

Pics for further detail:

[image]
Image texture, colours = should be, white = 1, black = 0, dark grey = 0.2, light grey = 0.5.

[image]
Colour ramp shading that gives the correct lighting on the model, the values in the ramp do not match the values of the paint, why?

[image]
Model with texture paint.